# fluid powered TYPO3 - the right settings for namespaces

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

I am using TYPO3 6.2.3, and Extensions from TER: (flux 7.0.0, fludipages 3.0.0, fluidcontent 4.0.0, VHS 1.8.5)
What is the right implementation of the namespaces? In the [Documentation](http://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/page-template.html) of fluidtypo3 is it <div

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}    
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/vhs/ViewHelpers">
```

On other [places](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent_bootstrap/blob/development/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Accordion.html) it is:

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Content" />
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/vhs/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">
```

I am also a bit confused if the `<f:layout name="Content" />` has to be inside or outside the namespace div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to define namespaces. The first one is the namespace tag in the fluid custom style notation:

```
{namespace x=Classname}
```

The other one is the formal XML notation for namespaces, thus if you use this, it makes your template fully XML compliant.

```
<someTag xmlns:xyz="http://typo3.org/ns/Some/Package/ViewHelpers" />
```

http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Templating.html#namespaces

For `TYPO3 CMS`, the resolution is the following.

1. Check `settings.namespaces.http://example\.org/url = className`, if match, use this
2. Check if the url starts with `http://typo3.org.ns/`, then everything after it will be interpreted as class name
3. Ignore it otherwise

Fore more information, please take a look at the samples in `typo3/sysext/fluid/Tests/Unit/Core/Parser/TemplateParserTest.php`

AFAIK namespaces that are detected and interpreted by fluid, are not printed into the output.

Comment: What do you mean by "Check settings.namespaces.http://example\.org/url = className"?

Comment: I mean the typoscript settings for your page. There you can define namespace --> classname mappings in the way pointed out in 2.

Answer (score 3):

The xmlns-defintions are just for your IDE to get code-completion. Adding it to the div will render it in frontend, I don't think that you want that.

This is my universal template for use in Templates AND Partials.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
      xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">

<head>
    <title>Template: Extension Index</title>
    <f:layout name="Default" />
</head>
<body>

{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}

<f:section name="main">

    // Content
    <f:render partial="Example/Ex" section="main">

</f:section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want that the html is getting rendered, you can add the attribute data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true" to the html tag. This feature is introduced in TYPO3 7.3 https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.3/Feature-66269-FluidRemoveViewHelperXmlnsAttributesAndSpecifiedHtmlTag.html

Answer (score 2):

**Q: What is the right implementation of the namespaces?**
A: I'm not sure myself. But in the case of vhs viewhelpers, this namespace declaration in a partial works for me (Typo3 6.2.12, vhs 2.3.2)

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

**Side note**
The following namespace declaration will not work, because it is not using the namespace notation (thx @kimomat):

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
```

On the other hand, for the namespace of my own viewhelpers, I have to use the above notation and it works

```
{namespace speciality = Tx_Speciality_ViewHelpers}
```

For reference, this is my complete partial.html

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\vhs\ViewHelpers}

<f:if condition="1">
  <f:then>SUCCESS</f:then>
  <f:else>ERROR</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: {namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers} is the old writing convention. {namespace v=FluidTYPO3\vhs\ViewHelpers} is the new convention with namespaces.